# How to get K-means unsupervised learning algorithm on orange3?

Tags: data-mining, orange

I installed orange3 using miniconda. I can not find K-Means unsupervised learning algorithm. where as other unsupervised learning algorithms are there.

I tried installing the educational add-on but K-means not in educational add-on. How can I get K-means on orange3?